# Share properties between maven plugin and the calling maven project pom

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have created a Maven Plugin P, which I want to use as a dependency in another Maven project A. I am providing some parameters to that the plugin P from the pom of Maven project A.

I want to set some properties in plugin P based on parameters provided by project A and want them to be referenced in pom of project A. How can I do that ?

I have tried setting properties for MavenProject in the plugin P. How can I refer them in the pom for project A?

Project A pom snippet:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sample-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>testing</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <param1>value1</param1>
                        <param2>value2</param2>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Plugin P code snippet

```
@Mojo( name = "testing")
public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo
{

    .
    . 
    @Parameter(property = "param1")
    private String param1;

    @Parameter(property = "param2")
    private String param2;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
    private org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("value1")){

              project.getProperties().setProperty("PROP1","val1");

        } else{
              project.getProperties().setProperty("PROP1","val3");    
        }

        if(param2.equalsIgnoreCase("value2")){

              project.getProperties().setProperty("PROP2","val2");

        } else{

              project.getProperties().setProperty("PROP2","val3");

        }


     }
}

I expect the PROP1 and PROP2 to be used in project A
```

Comment: Your approach looks fine. Which problems did you experience?

Comment: Thanks. What I want to achieve is, use the properties set in P plugin, in the pom of project A!!

Comment: Should I be using project property or system property to access in the project A pom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, if we add ${project} A as a parameter to the plugin configuration, we can add properties to it, which can be referred in project A pom.

Ex:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sample-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>testing</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <param1>value1</param1>
                        <param2>value2</param2>
                        <project>${project}</project>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

in Plugin one can use this Maven project

```
project.getProperties.setProperty("projectProperty",propertyValue);
```

Answer (score -2):

If i'm understanding this question correctly, try adding:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>sample-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

at the bottom of `Plugin P`'s `pom.xml` file, right before the end of `</project>`

I am not entirely sure this will even work as I have limited knowledge of Maven, but please let me know.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: Might want to look into having a `settings.xml` file then:
https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: This answer is wrong. Never add a plugin as a dependency.

Comment: That’s correct, plugin shouldn’t be added as a dependency. I was getting a another failure because of that.